# which javascript framework is better for Cakephp

Tags: javascript, cakephp

i am using cakephp framework for my project. but i am in confusion that which javascript framework i use for the project.
so please suggest me for this through which i get enough help from net.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

CakePHP 1.3 does have some [helpers](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1592/Js) that work with Prototype/Scriptaculous, Mootools/Mootools-more, and jQuery/jQuery UI, but I don't think that alone they are enough of a reason for choosing a JavaScript framework. (edited, thanks [deceze](https://stackoverflow.com/users/476/deceze)).

Any such MVC framework is concerned with proper structure of your application and getting the data to your view. When you get to designing your views, you are free to use whatever floats your boat, with minimal effect from/over your server-side code.

This being said, without necessary connection to CakePHP, I suggest you take a serious look at [jQuery](http://jquery.com/), it seems to be the popular choice nowadays and will help you write some nifty code.

Comment: Cake 1.3 supports some more frameworks. It's still not enough reason to choose or not choose a specific one though.